cutting & Pasting sub data from a cell in excel
I want to cut the 10 digits part numbers which always start with R9xxxxx and paste it in a seperate cell as I want to do this for 100s of rows... what formula can I use

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi Rami and welcome to Superuser . It would be best if you can post an example of data you have (and where it is on the Excel sheet) and where/what you want the formula to be/do.

Needs details or clarity - yes, the Q could be stated better, but it is not unclear. @Rami I'd suggest you rephrase your Q - see https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask for help

With H3= Sample text R9xxxxxx more text
The MID function used as in =MID(H3,13,8) will yield R9xxxxx picked out from the text in H3.
If the position of R9 varies, then substitute 13 by FIND("R9",H3) and it will do what you expect.
Note: A formula will not "PASTE" the result, just create a local copy in the cell you type the formula in.

R902239917 A4VG145EP0DP0X0/40NRN06T11FD4T1BS00-S
R902151103 A4VTG90 HW/32R-NLD10F001S
HAB4-4X BLASE NBR BG R901242647 Bladder Replacement
R902233499 / R902096451 A11VO130LR3DH1/10R-NZD12N00
R902248365 / R902248016 A11VO40DR/10L-NZC12K01
DOUBLE COIL NG6 BUSH BUTTON PM  R900765511  4WE 6 J6X/EG26N2K4K 283864005
R902211551 A4VG125HD9MT1/32R-NSF02F021S-S - round charge pump
R902211554 A2FO23/61L-PZB05-S
R902229000 A2FO23/61R-PZB06

here are some examples

the answer is what I'm looking for, but how can i paste the cut value into another cell

Your example is just a jumble of text. Beyond manual actions, an Excel macro is the only "automated" way to copy a value into a cell, e.g. record a macro - with 'Relative references' set - and then EDIT that macro to make it general.

Note also that the above formula can be part of your macro as the same MID(...) function is available there. -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function
